# Performance comparison between Thread and Task using c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, threadpool

I'm trying to understand the benefit between using common `Thread`s and `Task`s. The first is into `System.Threading` namespace and the latter is into `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace.
So, just for playing and get familiar with them, I wrote this program in `C#`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long ticksAtStart = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;

        new Thread(() => { ExecuteAsyn("Thread", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks); }).Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Using Thread: " + (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - ticksAtStart));

        ticksAtStart = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;

        Task g = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteAsyn("TPL", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks));
        Console.WriteLine("Using TPL: " + (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - ticksAtStart));

        g.Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ExecuteAsyn(string source, long ticksAtExecutionTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World! Using " + source + " the difference between initialization and execution is " + (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - ticksAtExecutionTime));
    }
}
```

So in base of my understandings, the Tasks should be more performant because they use Thread available into the `ThreadPool` while creating and starting new Thread can be very resource-consuming.
The program logs two events. The number of ticks CRL takes two create the two kinds of object and the ticks between the Thread is created and the actual execution of the provided delegate, in my case `ExecuteAsync`.

Something I did not expect occurs:

> Using Thread: 11372 Hello World! Using Thread the difference between
>   initialization and execution is 5482 Using TPL: 333004 Hello World!
>   Using TPL the difference between initialization and execution is 0

So it seems that using classical Threads is much more performant than using Tasks. 
But to me there is something strange here. Can anyone enlight me about this topic?
Thank you.

Comment: Depends what you want to do really, if you are creating a `Console.Writeline` Hello world application that starts one `thread` and one `task`, you are probably right and you have found your winner.

Comment: Use class `Stopwatch` to do your timings; `DateTime` is pretty useless for this.

Comment: If you are creating a server that needs to reuse threads both from the threadpool and completion ports monitor concurrency, needs a scheduler, which has a rich set of features that are baked into tasks, i doubt it will compare

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Executing a method the first time is always more costly: assemblies are lazily loaded, and the method may not be JITted yet.

For instance, if we take your benchmark (replacing DateTime by Stopwatch for precision) and call `Task.Factory.StartNew` once more:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    new Thread(() => { ExecuteAsyn("Thread", sw); }).Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Using Thread: " + sw.Elapsed);

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    Task g = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteAsyn("TPL", sw));
    Console.WriteLine("Using TPL: " + sw.Elapsed);

    g.Wait();

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    g = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteAsyn("TPL", sw));
    Console.WriteLine("Using TPL: " + sw.Elapsed);

    g.Wait();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void ExecuteAsyn(string source, Stopwatch sw)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World! Using " + source + " the difference between initialization and execution is " + (sw.Elapsed));
}
```

The result on my computer is:

> Using Thread: 00:00:00.0002071
>
> Hello World! Using Thread the difference between initialization and execution is 00:00:00.0004732
>
> Using TPL: 00:00:00.0046301
>
> Hello World! Using TPL the difference between initialization and execution is 00:00:00.0048927
>
> Using TPL: 00:00:00.0000027
>
> Hello World! Using TPL the difference between initialization and execution is 00:00:00.0001215

We can see that the second call is faster than the first one by three orders of magnitude.

Using a real benchmark framework (for instance, BenchmarkDotNet), we can get much more reliable results:

```
  Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
-------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|
 Threads | 137.426 us | 1.9170 us | 1.7932 us |
   Tasks |   2.384 us | 0.0322 us | 0.0301 us |
```

That said, a few additional remarks:

1. Your comparison is not fair. You're comparing the creation of a thread versus enqueuing a task on the threadpool via the tasks APIs. For fairness, you should use `ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueWorkItem` instead (which allows you to use the threadpool without the task API)
2. Whether to use Thread or Task shouldn't be a matter of performance. It's really more a matter of convenience. It's highly unlikely that the performance gap would make any difference in your application, unless you're dealing with low-latency or very high throughput.

Comment: For large workloads threads run about twice as fast see [the answer below/above in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60347479/5719295)